# How do I setup a VPN behind Tor in Tails?

Tags: privacy, vpn, tor

I would like the following setup:
Tails -> Tor -> VPN.

My limited knowledge on the matter tells me that this would render me "anonymous" to the VPN and provide me with some privacy with regards to bad apples on the Tor-network.

So how would I go about áchieving this? I'll be using one of the well-known VPN providers (TorGuard, PIA, or the like), if that makes a difference.

Comment: The VPN providers you stated require a paid account. Hiding behind Tor is of no use if you login to your VPN using an account, which can identify you.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser Bundle has a built in proxy, if you want to tunnel a software through Tor (In this case your VPN Client), you need to tell that software to use the Tor proxy. The flow goes like this:
VPN Client > Tor (Via localhost proxy) > VPN Server

[This guide](http://tor.searchprivate.com/docs/tor-doc-web.html.en) is about setting up a proxy for a browser. I don't know what VPN software you use, so I cannot give you specific instructions regarding that. You should be able to adapt that guide to your VPN client, if not, feel free to ask about a specific VPN client.

You should note that Tails [recommends against this setup](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/vpn_support/).